# Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) Ingress w/auth-url

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I wish I could have found my answer elsewhere, but the lack of documentation has sent me groveling for help :)

I have been following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) as a starting point. I can follow the steps through to the end with great success. But when I modify the ingress to do what I am trying to accomplish, nothing happens.

The tutorial has you create an ingress with the following .yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx
    servicePort: 80
```

What I am trying to do is modify the ingress so that it can utilize the [auth-url annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md#external-authentication) and in the end my ingress.yaml I am failing with looks like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://someauth.com/path/to/my/auth
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx
    servicePort: 80
```

In order to use the annotation, I found that I needed to include the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation to use the appropriate ingress. Basically though, this does nothing. I can hit the backend nginx cluster without my auth getting touched. Like these annotations are not even there.

Does GKE not support the `nginx` ingress controller? Is something fundamentally wrong with my yaml? Does the gce ingress controller have an annotation that could accomplish the same thing?

What I am trying to accomplish is: A client makes a call to my service, the loadbalancer/proxy first authenticates the request with an external endpoint, if auth is successful, the proxy sends the call along to my service (all without a single redirect response sent to the client). Basically what [nginx auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) does which is what I assume this `auth-url` annotation leverages under the covers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

GKE has its own Ingress Controller. It is called GKE Ingress Controller. If you want to use Nginx Ingress Controller, you need to manage it yourself.

Looks like `auth-url annotation` works only on Nginx Ingress Controller. So, you have to run Nginx Ingress Controller first.

See [this post](http://rahmonov.me/posts/nginx-ingress-controller/) on how to do that on GKE.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does look pretty thorough and amazing! Nice writeup :) If I roll my own ingress controller like this, do the ingress servers run in their own auto-scaling cluster? Or rather, where do these controllers run? I am wanting to keep the cpu of my backend service independent from the controller, if that makes sense.

Comment: They run in their own namespace within the same cluster. They wouldn't be able to watch for changes in actual ingress files if they were in another cluster, would they? :)